# Compact notation for the product $k(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+n)$?

Tags: reference-request, notation, binomial-coefficients, products

Is there a convenient and compact notation for writing the product $A$, below, in a compact way?

$$A=k(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+n)$$ i.e. a product of $n$ consecutive integers starting from $k$.

This arises from some diagonals of Pascal's triangle.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials

Comment: Please don't write "Solved" in your title like you did. Instead, you should answer your question yourself (or let Wojowu do it), or delete the question if you don't think it will be useful to anyone.

Comment: @Arnaud as there are upvoted answers, I don't think OP can delete the question. It would be nice if OP were to "accept" an answer by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Comment: Hmmm it's interesting that there are two close votes for lack of context, yet I don't see how much more context you could have for a question simply asking for notation.

Comment: I refrained from accepting an answer because they both seemed equally good. I've now accepted one for the sake of marking the question as closed.

Comment: @GerryMyerson There were no answers when I posted that comment.

Comment: @hardmath Fair enough.

Comment: Thanks! Note that to hit the last term $(k+n)$ we need $n+1$ terms in the product, so the rising factorial (aka Pochhammer symbol) notation would be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Concrete Mathematics, by  Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik, the notation used for "rising powers" is 
$$
m^{\overline{n}}
$$ 
meaning 
$$
m(m+1)\cdots (m+n-1)
$$
with $n$ terms being multiplied.

Many other authors do use the $m^{(n)}$ notation for it, but the advatage of the one listed first is that it nicely unifies with falling powers 
$$ m^{\underline{n}} = m(m-1)(m-2)\cdots(m-n+1)$$

Mathematica uses the name "Pochammer" function, which is valid in that Paochammer did early work involving such products, but IMHO that makes it sound like something arcane and advanced.

Note that the words "factorial powers" are connected to both of these:
$$
1^{\overline{n}} = n^{\underline{n}} = n!
$$
and that as long as the exponent used is an integer, these can be defined for any real $x$, as in 
$$
\left(\frac32\right)^{\overline{3}} = \frac{105}{8}
$$

Comment: I would disagree that "Pochammer symbol" sounds any more arcane or advanced than "factorial symbol", "summation symbol" or many other things we use regularly in mathematics.  Things are given names to make it easy to refer to them and since it's necessary to explain the term "rising factorial" it's no clearer than "Pochammer symbol" in this context.

Comment: @postmortes - "Rising factorial" is at least somewhat descriptive, even though it may require explanation. "Pochhammer symbol" is not descriptive at all; a person's name tells nothing about the idea. It may suggest that the idea is so complicated or obscure that it can't be given a short descriptive name.

Comment: @hardmath -- Right you are, I had the incorrect spelling.  And that extra "h" does clarify everything considerably.

Answer (score 10):

As [Wojowu](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345678/compact-notation-for-kk1k2#comment6886746_3345678) mentions, this is the rising factorial, defined by:

$$k^{(n)}=k(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+n-1)$$

Using product notation you could also write:

$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(k+i)=k(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+n-1)$$

And in terms of the factorial:

$$\frac{(k+n-1)!}{(k-1)!}=k(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+n-1)$$